# How to join the data and compare with another access database

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access-2013

I know that we can combine 2 datatables from 2 separate database on the same server as like below.

```sql
SELECT a.userID, b.usersFirstName, b.usersLastName  
FROM databaseA.dbo.TableA a 
inner join database B.dbo.TableB b ON a.userID=b.userID
```

But here's what I want.. 
I need to get UserEmailAddress from DB2 based on DB1.Table1's UserName *when the DueDate is overdue..*
The common thing that able to link DB1 & DB2 is the UserName in both table.
But in DB2, the Username is the combination of UsersLastName and UsersFirstName.
Like below :

```
Select * from DB1.Table1 and DB2.Table2 
where DB1.Table1.UserName = DB2.Table2.UserName 
(**DB2.Table2.UserName = [UsersLastName] + ', ' + [UsersFirstName] )
when DB1.Table1.DueDate>TodayDate
```

[image]

I'm using ASP.net, C# and Microsoft Access database.

How am I supposed to write the query?

Comment: it will help if you put your table structure in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT TB2.UserEmailAddress FROM Table1 TB1
INNER JOIN Table2 TB2 ON TB2.UserName = TB1.UserName
```

I'm not quite sure this is the answer you are looking for, please give a better description and show us some table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need DB1? I see that you can get all the information you want from DB2.

To join these two tables you can use:

```
SELECT DB1.UserName, DB2.UsersFirstName, DB2.UsersLastName, DB2.UserName, DB2.UsersEmail
FROM DB1 DB1, DB2 DB2
WHERE DB1.UserName = DB2.UsersFirstName + ',' + DB2.UsersLastName
```